# Is there a difference in Scala between Seq[T] and T*?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

My IDE's tooling shows that `xs` has type `Int*` in the following snippet:

```
def accept(xs: Int*) = true
```

The language reference, however, says that a repeated parameter declared as `T*` has type `Seq[T]`. Is there a difference between `Int*` and `Seq[Int]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are different, and it's somewhere between bug and regrettable feature that T* leaks into type signatures.

[Repeated parameter typed as T* rather than Seq[T]](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4176)

Comment: Assuming there was no concern about breaking existing code, what would the spec say about the type of the repeated parameters outside the method? Is it known or is it a matter of debate too? I feel the return type in `def f(t: T*) = t` should be `Seq[T]`.

Comment: It should unquestionably be Seq[T].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are different. See, e.g., [Overriding a repeated class parameter in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512402/overriding-a-repeated-class-parameter-in-scala/5514109#5514109)